# Context when passing option to plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

I'm having some problems with the context of an object being passed as an option to a plugin. I call the function, however when the plugin does it's thing, the context of 'attach' changes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('article > header').stickyHeader({
       attach: $(this).siblings('h2')
    });
});

$.fn.stickyHeader = function(settings) {
  // settings
  settings = $.extend({
    attach: false
  }, settings);

  var $this = $(this);
  var $attach = settings.attach;
  console.log($attach);

  // DO STUFF

  return false;
};
```

The console logs "jQuery()" I think with the context being the document. How do I get the correct context from within the plugin? Ideally "jQuery(h2)".

After digging around i've fiddled with the following with no results:

```
var $attach = $.proxy( $attach, this );
```

Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/mfpYK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('article > header').stickyHeader({
        attach: $('article > header').siblings('h2')
    });
});
```

`$(this)` is obviously `$(document)` in your original code.

Comment: Yes, you're correct that works like a charm. **However** the attach option will actually 'attach' another object to the header object, so in your example only the last h2 gets attached. That's why is important that I include $(this).

Comment: My code would give an array of two `h2` dom objects when run on your fiddle. What exactly do you want `console.log($attach);` to output?